# Datetime displayed with pm and am

Tags: c#, datetime

```
[DisplayName("Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}")]
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

> The date is: 2015-09-03 14:22:43
>
> But it's displayed as: 2015-09-03 02:22:43

How can I make it displayed as 2015-09-03 14:22:43?

Comment: See: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#hhSpecifier) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#HH_Specifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HH` for `00-24 hours` and `hh` for `AM/PM`

So, Replace

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}")]
```

with

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}")]
```

Comment: Thanks. Will mark as answer when possible

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}")]
                                                 ^^
                                                  |___ This will specify the time as 24hours
```